# What's the best way to fit a set of points in an image one or more good lines using RANSAC using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, ransac

What's the best way to fit a set of points in an image one or more good lines using RANSAC using OpenCV?

Is RANSAC is the most efficient way to fit a line?

Answer (score 5):

RANSAC is not the most efficient but it is better for a large number of outliers. Here is how to do it using opencv:

A useful structure-

```
struct SLine
{
    SLine():
        numOfValidPoints(0),
        params(-1.f, -1.f, -1.f, -1.f)
    {}
    cv::Vec4f params;//(cos(t), sin(t), X0, Y0)
    int numOfValidPoints;
};
```

Total Least squares used to make a fit for a successful pair

```
cv::Vec4f TotalLeastSquares(
    std::vector<cv::Point>& nzPoints,
    std::vector<int> ptOnLine)
{
    //if there are enough inliers calculate model
    float x = 0, y = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0, xy = 0, w = 0;
    float dx2, dy2, dxy;
    float t;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < nzPoints.size(); ++i )
    {
        x += ptOnLine[i] * nzPoints[i].x;
        y += ptOnLine[i] * nzPoints[i].y;
        x2 += ptOnLine[i] * nzPoints[i].x * nzPoints[i].x;
        y2 += ptOnLine[i] * nzPoints[i].y * nzPoints[i].y;
        xy += ptOnLine[i] * nzPoints[i].x * nzPoints[i].y;
        w += ptOnLine[i];
    }

    x /= w;
    y /= w;
    x2 /= w;
    y2 /= w;
    xy /= w;

    //Covariance matrix
    dx2 = x2 - x * x;
    dy2 = y2 - y * y;
    dxy = xy - x * y;

    t = (float) atan2( 2 * dxy, dx2 - dy2 ) / 2;
    cv::Vec4f line;
    line[0] = (float) cos( t );
    line[1] = (float) sin( t );

    line[2] = (float) x;
    line[3] = (float) y;

    return line;
}
```

The actual RANSAC

```
SLine LineFitRANSAC(
    float t,//distance from main line
    float p,//chance of hitting a valid pair
    float e,//percentage of outliers
    int T,//number of expected minimum inliers 
    std::vector<cv::Point>& nzPoints)
{
    int s = 2;//number of points required by the model
    int N = (int)ceilf(log(1-p)/log(1 - pow(1-e, s)));//number of independent trials

    std::vector<SLine> lineCandidates;
    std::vector<int> ptOnLine(nzPoints.size());//is inlier
    RNG rng((uint64)-1);
    SLine line;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        //pick two points
        int idx1 = (int)rng.uniform(0, (int)nzPoints.size());
        int idx2 = (int)rng.uniform(0, (int)nzPoints.size());
        cv::Point p1 = nzPoints[idx1];
        cv::Point p2 = nzPoints[idx2];

        //points too close - discard
        if (cv::norm(p1- p2) < t)
        {
            continue;
        }

        //line equation ->  (y1 - y2)X + (x2 - x1)Y + x1y2 - x2y1 = 0 
        float a = static_cast<float>(p1.y - p2.y);
        float b = static_cast<float>(p2.x - p1.x);
        float c = static_cast<float>(p1.x*p2.y - p2.x*p1.y);
        //normalize them
        float scale = 1.f/sqrt(a*a + b*b);
        a *= scale;
        b *= scale;
        c *= scale;

        //count inliers
        int numOfInliers = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nzPoints.size(); ++i)
        {
            cv::Point& p0 = nzPoints[i];
            float rho      = abs(a*p0.x + b*p0.y + c);
            bool isInlier  = rho  < t;
            if ( isInlier ) numOfInliers++;
            ptOnLine[i]    = isInlier;
        }

        if ( numOfInliers < T)
        {
            continue;
        }

        line.params = TotalLeastSquares( nzPoints, ptOnLine);
        line.numOfValidPoints = numOfInliers;
        lineCandidates.push_back(line);
    }

    int bestLineIdx = 0;
    int bestLineScore = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lineCandidates.size(); i++)
    {
        if (lineCandidates[i].numOfValidPoints > bestLineScore)
        {
            bestLineIdx = i;
            bestLineScore = lineCandidates[i].numOfValidPoints;
        }
    }

    if ( lineCandidates.empty() )
    {
        return SLine();
    }
    else
    {
        return lineCandidates[bestLineIdx];
    }
}
```

Comment: why did you used Leastsquare when you were trying to get line's parameter ?

Comment: also I've one more question; if I am trying to use RANSAC after hough transform what should be the inputs to RANSAC and how hough transform helps RANSAC in detecting the exact line ? 
I am trying to follow caltech lane detection algorithm

Comment: @Sara I used Total Least squares. Also known as SVD. It is a little more robust that simple least squares. LS is the simplest way to get the line parameters.

Comment: @Sara Hough transform is designed in mind to extract multiple shapes/lines under a very high noise. It is also very heavy. For many application it is not real time.

Comment: @Sara RANSAC works assuming a prior know level of outliers. It is actually one of the inputs to the RANSAC algorithm. RANSAC is expected to fail for a high level of ouliers. In that case you will have no choice but to use Hough transform. I am not familiar with the "Caltech lane detection algorithm" So I am afraid I can't advise you on it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  Caltech algorithm used both Hough transform and RANSAC "Bezeir" but it used Hough transform before RANSAC but what I've understood that it takes the a window around the detected line from hough transform as an input for RANAC

Comment: @Sara Looks very interesting. The inventor has open source code on github: https://github.com/mohamedadaly/caltech-lane-detection

Comment: yes I downloaded it before but I've failed to make it work successfully, as I've used windows 7 and visual studio 2010 with opencv library and I used getopt library that he used in linux but it didn't work I've link error and other errors and tried to solve them but I've given up 
so what I am doing is trying to understand the code or the concept but sometimes I don't get it as I am not expert

Comment: @Sara yeah, windows would be difficult because he compiled it only in Linux. Maybe try it in a virtual machine?

Comment: I didn't work on the compiled files I tried to make a new project in visual studio and includes all the .h and .cpp file i took the source code only

Comment: Try looking at his Makefile. Maybe it will help

Comment: Thanks for this. Are you sure the Least Squares implementation is accurate ? I haven't seen that algorithm before. Any sources ? Thank you !

Comment: @nnrales It is accurate. I tried it on real life problems. Using SVD and total least squares has a solid mathematical basis: http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/SystemID/CourseNotes/TotalLeastSquares.pdf

Comment: Thank you Yonatan !

Comment: This answer makes more sense. RANSAC gets more accurate as you increase the number of outliers. OP first asks best way to do RANSAC and then if RANSAC is the best.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Least Mean Square metod](http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/line-of-best-fit.html). It's faster and simplier than RANSAC.

Also take look at OpenCV's [fitLine](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#fitline) method.

RANSAC performs better when you have a lot of outliers in your data, or a complex hypothesis.

Comment: Oh thanks so much. I think that Least Mean Square won't work because I have a set of points and I want the bests lines that has some properties such as a x angle and x meters from the center of image.

Comment: There's also RHO, which is actually PROSAC, a derivative of RANSAC.