# Using OpenCV Hough Tranform for line detection in 2D point cloud

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, line

I have tried my best to find out how to use OpenCV for line detection. However, I cannot find the examples that I'm looking for. I want to use it to find lines in simple 2-d point clouds. As a test I want to use the following points:

[image]

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.randint(1,101,400)  # Random points.
b = np.random.randint(1,101,400)  # Random points.

for i in range(0, 90, 2):  # A line to detect
    a = np.append(a, [i+5])
    b = np.append(b, [0.5*i+30])

plt.plot(a, b, '.')
plt.show()
```

I have found a lot of initial examples of how the Hough Tranform works. However, when it comes to code examples, I can only find that images have been used.

Is there a way to use the OpenCV Hough Transform to detect the line in a set of points, or can you recommend any other methods or libraries?

---- Edit ----

After reading some great ansewers I feel like I scould discribe what i intent to use it for a little bit better. I have a high resolution 2D LiDAR and need to extract walls from the data. A typicle scan can look like this:
[image]

Where the "correct output" would look something like this:
[image]

After I have done some more research I suspect that the Hough transform is less than optimal to use in this case. Any tips on what i should look for?

(If anyone is interested, the LiDAR and wall extraction is used to generate a map and navigate a robot.)

Thanks, Jakob

Comment: Please expand on why you think that Hough is less than optimal? Dilation and erosion as preprocessing could be useful to connect neighbouring dots. Something interesting you could do here is the limitation of the hough space to horizontal and vertical lines.

Comment: Well the Hough transform is used on images and I would prefer not to be forced to discretize the collected data to any lower than 1mm, which would yield an image of 50'000 x 40'000 px in this example. 

However the code you suggested did manage to somewhat extract lines when i applied it to the collected data. Not good enough though (yet).

One aspect I believe should help is that the collected data comes in order (counter-clockwise). I feel like there should be a way to use that information to extract lines.

Comment: Can you provide the original data? Or any excerpt of the original data?

Comment: Here is a drive link to a text file, the two arrays in the file represent x and y coordinates where elemets correspond by index. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EnSOr2FYjIdqG1RdFgTkgsoEhVcG7Tl_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, i have to do the same as you. have you done the wall tracking properly? I need to do it for my thesis. can i contact with you please? @JakobVinkas

Comment: @Kazi I am working on a large navigation project and the wall-detection is only a small part of it. I have still not found a proper solution to the problem but I would love to discuss it further and see if we can trade insights that might be usefull. You can discuss it here or contact me at jakobvinkas@gmail.com.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to implement Hough Transformation yourself following these [slides](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF4300/h09/undervisningsmateriale/hough09.pdf) skipping the Edge Detection part.

Alternatively you could create an image from your list of points such as

```
#create an image from list of points
x_shape = int(np.max(a) - np.min(a))
y_shape = int(np.max(b) - np.min(b))

im = np.zeros((x_shape+1, y_shape+1))

indices = np.stack([a-1,b-1], axis =1).astype(int)
im[indices[:,0], indices[:,1]] = 1

plt.imshow(im)

#feed to opencv as usual
```

following the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396141/python-numpy-2d-array-indexing)

EDIT: Do not feed to OpenCV but use instead skimage such as described here in the [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_line_hough_transform.html):

```
import numpy as np

from skimage.transform import (hough_line, hough_line_peaks,
                               probabilistic_hough_line)
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage import data

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm


# Constructing test image
#image = np.zeros((100, 100))
#idx = np.arange(25, 75)
#image[idx[::-1], idx] = 255
#image[idx, idx] = 255

image = im

# Classic straight-line Hough transform
h, theta, d = hough_line(image)

# Generating figure 1
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 6))
ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(image, cmap=cm.gray)
ax[0].set_title('Input image')
ax[0].set_axis_off()

ax[1].imshow(np.log(1 + h),
             extent=[np.rad2deg(theta[-1]), np.rad2deg(theta[0]), d[-1], d[0]],
             cmap=cm.gray, aspect=1/1.5)
ax[1].set_title('Hough transform')
ax[1].set_xlabel('Angles (degrees)')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Distance (pixels)')
ax[1].axis('image')

ax[2].imshow(image, cmap=cm.gray)
for _, angle, dist in zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)):
    y0 = (dist - 0 * np.cos(angle)) / np.sin(angle)
    y1 = (dist - image.shape[1] * np.cos(angle)) / np.sin(angle)
    ax[2].plot((0, image.shape[1]), (y0, y1), '-r')
ax[2].set_xlim((0, image.shape[1]))
ax[2].set_ylim((image.shape[0], 0))
ax[2].set_axis_off()
ax[2].set_title('Detected lines')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Line finding using the Probabilistic Hough Transform
image = data.camera()
edges = canny(image, 2, 1, 25)
lines = probabilistic_hough_line(edges, threshold=10, line_length=5,
                                 line_gap=3)

# Generating figure 2
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5), sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(image, cmap=cm.gray)
ax[0].set_title('Input image')

ax[1].imshow(edges, cmap=cm.gray)
ax[1].set_title('Canny edges')

ax[2].imshow(edges * 0)
for line in lines:
    p0, p1 = line
    ax[2].plot((p0[0], p1[0]), (p0[1], p1[1]))
ax[2].set_xlim((0, image.shape[1]))
ax[2].set_ylim((image.shape[0], 0))
ax[2].set_title('Probabilistic Hough')

for a in ax:
    a.set_axis_off()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Hough won't work on disjointed points. It requires the actual lines, with points next to each other.

Comment: The points do not need to be neighbours. For details regarding the algorithm have a look here - it specifically contains an image of two disjoint points and how hough would work in that case. http://me.umn.edu/courses/me5286/vision/Notes/2015/ME5286-Lecture9.pdf

Comment: could you please replace `#feed to opencv as usual` with a POC code that shows your method actually works in this case?

Comment: I you have any more questions, I am happy to expand.

Comment: @NikolasRieble If you get some time over, please take a look at the edit I made to the post where I explain my problem more in-depth.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach

- Convert image to grayscale
- Threshold to obtain binary image
- Perform morphological operations to connect contours and smooth image
- Find lines

---

After converting to grayscale, we threshold image to obtain a binary image

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

Next we perform [morphological operations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to connect contours

[image]

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=3)
```

Finally we find the line using [`cv2.HoughLinesP()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html)

[image]

```
minLineLength = 550
maxLineGap = 70
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(close,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(36,255,12),3)
```

Instead of using `cv2.HoughLinesP()`, an alternative method is to find contours and filter using `cv2.contourArea()`. The largest contour will be our line.

---

Full code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=3)

minLineLength = 550
maxLineGap = 70
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(close,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(36,255,12),3)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely won't be able to use Hough transform to detect lines in a set of points. Hough transform works with images. Better yet, binarized images with edges marked as `1` and background stays as `0`. So, forget about the Hough transform.

For your particular case I'd suggest some kind of RANSAC algorithm, which looks for specific points following some rules, ignoring everything else. Though, in your case you have a lot (=too much) noise. If you can keep the noise points below 50%, RANSAC will do the trick. You may read the details here: [OpenCV - Ransac fitting line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020496/opencv-ransac-fitting-line)

Or here's the Wiki with the most generic explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If you look at the edit i made you can se the amount of noise present in the real implementation. One "scan" is yields 8400 measurement points.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some (alot) of time with the problem I eventually reached a solution that I was sattisfied with.

My solution is to go through the scan data as it is read (as a revolving scanner) and iteratively look at smalles sections of the data, then running a custom ransac algorithm to fit a line to the current segment.

Then if the segment satisfies the critera for a possible line the segment is extended and checked again. This is then repeated for all small segments of data in different ways. **In short, I used a custom, self written from scratch, iterative ransac line fit.**

If we take a similar example to what I initially gave:
[image]

The following result is now generated by the algorith:
[image]

And comparing to the actual (wall) map of the enviroment we can see the following comparison:

[image]

Which I would say is good enough. Another important note is that the algorith can be run for multiple scans of data with the enviroment naturally chaning slightly inbetween all of the scans (taking quite some time to execute):

[image]

As can bee seen there are some extra walls that are not a part of the map, which is to be expected and also some faulty findings that can be filtered since they are clear outliers.

Now for the code.... The final solution is a 300 lines long python script converted though a `.pyx` file and compiled using `Cython` in order to improve time complexity. If the code or maybe more importantly a psuedo code (since my implementation is tweeked to my specfic need) is wanted I can provide it given that someone will enjoy using/reading it :)

Comment: I would be interested in pseudo-code.

Comment: @jakobvinkas can you provide your code please?