# How to get a best RMS error in "fitting line by points" process with a user-specified number of removal?

Tags: c++, algorithm, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have 30 data points(x, y) to fit a best line now and I know how to do this part.

However, a "user-specified number of removal" variable must be involved.

For example, the variable is 10 so I should remove 10 points in the dataset, which means fitting line by 20 points.

The question is How to decide which point to be removed and get a minized RMS error?

Let me show two images for instance:

[fit the line by all points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h62dQ.png)

[remove 10 points and get a new line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W47Qx.png)

Comment: 1) fit line on all points, 2) remove N points with largest error, 3) fit again. Eventually repeat N times 2) removing only one point and 3)

Comment: @Miki: I don't see what you mean by "eventually" there. I agree that there are two possible implementations: Fit, and then remove N points at once, or repeatedly fit, and remove one point at a time. The difference is that with the latter approach, removal of the first point affects the fit and therefore the choice of the second point to remove.

Comment: @MSalters yes exactly. _"eventually"_ isn't the correct word, I should've said _"As an alternative approach..."_

Comment: @Miki
Thanks for your answers, but there is a problem.
Actually, I know what I want is neither remove one point at a time and then repeat nor remove N points at once.

Let's say, when I tested this 30 points case in Cognex VisionPro, if I set N=5, the choosen indexs of points to remove were 1, 3, 5, 6 and 8, then I changed N to 6, it's indexs became 2, 4, 7, 9 , 10, 11 which was totally different.
At the time, RMS error was dramatically reduced.

Therefore, I think two methods above is not correct.

Comment: @MSalters 
Thanks for your answer.

As I mentioned above, two way to do this is not correct.

The brutal way I figure out is that remove 10 points randomly and then go through all possilbility to see which RMS error is mimimum, but this is too time-comsuming to do.

Comment: then read bout "ransac"

Comment: @Miki
Can you tell me more details?
I test the code here [RANSAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020496/whats-the-best-way-to-fit-a-set-of-points-in-an-image-one-or-more-good-lines-us) _italic_ **bold**, it seems not what I want.
I want to remove a certain number of points by the method.